# Query for a deeply nested attribute in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, querying

New to rails, so appologies in advance for the newb question. I'm trying to query or sort posts by a deeply nested attribute(?):

```
 user_id: 3,
 type_id: 1,
 properties: {
              'title' => 'foo',
              'body' => 'bar',
              'category' => ['','foobish'] }
```

In the rails console I can get to this by doing `Post.last.properties[category][1]`

but I'm looking to be able to get to this in the posts controller, how should I go about doing this? The closest I've seemed to get is `@foo = Post.where(properties: [Category: ['', 'foobish']])`

Comment: In order to query a structure like that, you'd need to use a DB that allows for querying json.  I believe you'd need to use something like postgres, serialize the props as json, and probably hand-write queries to do that type of query.  Perhaps Rails can manage the integration better than hand-writing the queries but I'm not experienced there.  Check out the docs under JSON: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thank you for that